# SQL Server AFTER INSERT trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want this trigger to be fired after an insert is made with the text `married` on the `marital_status` column, this is what I have so far

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[marriage]
ON  [dbo].[applicant_personal_info]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF (SELECT [marital_status] FROM inserted) = 'married'
 BEGIN
     INSERT INTO [dbo].[applicant_marriage_info]([dom])
     VALUES('abc')
 END
END
```

Answer (score 11):

The issue you'll run into here comes from the fact that SQL Server doesn't have the "FOR EACH ROW" triggers that Oracle does. You have to write your triggers to handle multi-row changes, i.e. the INSERTED or DELETED virtual tables can have more than one row in them.

If such an update were to happen, your trigger would fail, since `(SELECT [marital_status] FROM inserted)` would return multiple rows, and subqueries have to return a single value to be used in a direct comparison.

The trigger would probably have to look something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[marriage] ON  [dbo].[applicant_personal_info] FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF EXISTS (SELECT [marital_status] FROM INSERTED WHERE marital_status = 'married')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[applicant_marriage_info] ([dom])
        SELECT
            'abc' --Replace with whatever you're really inserting
        FROM INSERTED
        WHERE marital_status = 'married'
    END
END
```

Answer (score 8):

So this trigger is actually pretty close to what you need.  Now the problem here is that only one row will be inserted into applicant_marriage_info if there's any rows in inserted.  Is this what you actually want?  What happens if there's multiple rows inserted at once?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[marriage]
ON  [dbo].[applicant_personal_info]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[applicant_marriage_info]([dom])
    SELECT 'abc' 
    FROM inserted 
    WHERE marital_status = 'married'
END
```

You'll probably need more columns than what I've shown.

Comment: It should be done every time this data is entered

Comment: Then one way is to replace the last part with `BEGIN INSERT INTO [dbo].[applicant_marriage_info]([dom]) SELECT 'abc' FROM inserted WHERE marital_status = 'married' END`

Comment: I've changed the sample code a bit to account for this.  You don't need the IF EXISTS bit any more.  Just run the query against inserted and load that data into the other table.  You'll probably need more columns than I've got shown, some sort of ID probably, but you probably get the idea.